# BizTalk 2009/2010 Change the FTP Adapter's Retry Interval

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2009, biztalk-2010

Is there a way to change the default 5 minute retry interval on the FTP adapter? If looked at the FTP adapter settings as well as the actual ftp send port configurations. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

Yes indeed there is.  It is not specific to the FTP adapter which is probably why you can't find it.

In **BizTalk Server Administration**, navigate the tree to your send port.  Right click it and choose **Properties**.  In the left pane, click **Transport Advanced Options**.  You can configure the retry interval and count settings here.

More information is available [on MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa578109%28v=bts.10%29.aspx) (scroll down the page a bit).